# Выравнивание текста вправо

Tags: форматирование, c++

Мне нужно напечатать текст такого вида:

```
10000:                  1
    1:                 55
 1204:                312
```

Не получается отформатировать текст,

```
cout << right << "job: " << setw(10) << 20 << endl;
```

Вот так не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста! Знаю что решение где то на поверхности, но никак не могу допереть.

**Обновление**

Не изменяется ничего. Возможно я неправильно выразил свою мысль, когда привел эту строку в качестве примера, но я имею ввиду, что хочу достигнуть отформатированного текста, приведенного выше.

В общем, мне нужно добиться форматирования этого кода:

```
fout << setw(5) << "fname: " << setw(15) << fname << endl;
fout << setw(5) << "lname: " << setw(15) << lname << endl;
fout << setw(5) << "job: " << setw(15) << job << endl;
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

У Вас размер поля (`setw()`) *меньше* размера данных, поэтому и не получается

Код:

```
cout << setw(10) << "xaxa: " << setw(10) << 22 << '\n';
cout << setw(10) << "xa: " << setw(10) << 1122 << '\n';
cout << setw(10) << "xa-xaxa: " << setw(10) << 2 << '\n';
```

выводит

```
    xaxa:         22
      xa:       1122
 xa-xaxa:          2
```